# How to exclude string from sumifs in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I want to exclude multiple strings off the sum. So I put them inside the brackets. Hoping they'll sum everything without these strings. But unluckily, not working.

I want B14 to result 80 - exclude A2 and A7. So I put `=SUMIFS(A2:A7,{"<>"&A2,"<>"&A7},E2:E7)`, but no luck.

I put the sample here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18bLk5gv2TwuVwTeR1LoMzWU7tqrvjjmZmGrp03-sl0w/edit#gid=0

I'm very new to google sheets. So please suggest.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E7, A2:A7, "<>Transport", A2:A7, "<>Cutlery")
```

Or:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E7, A2:A7, "<>"&A2, A2:A7, "<>"&A7)
```

Result:

[image]